# Vuex - Update entire object inside array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Inside my Vuex mutation, I want to replace an array element in my state, as shown below:

```
UPDATE_MAILING(state, mailing) {
    let index = _.findIndex(state.mailings, {id: mailing.id});

    state.mailings[index] = mailing
}
```

But this does not update my template bound to this array. How can I reactively update the array element?

Comment: Instead of doing it inside mutation, you can do the same inside getters!

Comment: As far as I understood if any changes happen to you array(inside state) it should be automatically update in your template html. To acheive this whatever the array you want to change get that array from state in computed function. (In computed whenever its dependecy(here your array) changes it will automatically update template html)

Comment: This link might help. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Basic-Example

Comment: could you please tell me is my comment helped?? Did i understand question correctly?

Answer (score 8):

You should use `Vue.$set` (or `this.$set` inside Vue instance):

```js
UPDATE_MAILING(state, mailing) {
    let index = state.mailings.findIndex(item => item.id === mailing.id)
    Vue.$set(state.mailings, index, mailing)
}
```

Docs: [Vue.js → Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

Answer (score 4):

As described in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays), you could use either [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) or [`Vue.set()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) to reactively replace the array item:

```
mutations: {
  UPDATE_MAILING(state, mailing) {
    const index = state.mailings.findIndex(x => x.id === mailing.id)
    state.mailings.splice(index, 1, mailing)

    // OR:
    Vue.set(state.mailings, index, mailing)
  }
}
```

I prefer `splice` here, as it doesn't require importing `Vue`, which also makes it easier to test.

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/j3l6oykl89?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fstore.js)

Comment: what's the difference between using this and `Vue.$set`?

Comment: This is just an alternate method, as described in the [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays). I prefer `splice` here, as it doesn't require importing `Vue`, which also makes it easier to test.