# How to dynamic change state in another vuex component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket, vuex, vuetify.js

I've got a problem with state in component. I have websocket and over it come changes, which I put it in some state. It's ok in one component, it dynamically changes value. But, when I go to the next component (vue-router). Its state changes as well, but is not dynamic. hmmmmm... in console.log changes coming, but not change value in another component.

How can I make it?

Let's see some code:

Here my action, with change states

```
actions: {
    play(ctx, array){

         axios.get('http://localhost/task_run?task_id='+array.id)
        var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080', "protocol");
        conn.onmessage = function (ev) {
            ctx.commit('procent', {key:array.key, val:ev.data});
            ctx.commit('procentOne', {key:array.key, val:ev.data});
            console.log('Message: ', ev);
        };
    },
},
mutations: {
    procent(state, val){
        var array =  JSON.parse(val.val);
        state.process[val.key] = array.procent;
        state.processOnePersone[array.comp] = array.procent;
    }

},
state: {
    process: [],
    processOnePersone:[],
},
getters: {
    process(state){
        return state.process
    },
processOnePersone(state){
        return state.processOnePersone;
    }
}
```

I have one compenent, where it works

```
<v-progress-circular
                                :rotate="-90"
                                :size="50"
                                :width="5"
                                :value="process[key]"
                                color="primary"
                        >
                            {{ process[key] }}
                        </v-progress-circular>
         <script>
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';

export default {
    name: 'taskListComponent',
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['process',]),
    },
}
```

And component where it doesn't work

```
<v-progress-circular
                                :rotate="-90"
                                :size="50"
                                :width="5"
                                :value="processOnePersone[key]"
                                color="primary"
                        >
                            {{ processOnePersone[key] }}
                        </v-progress-circular>
         <script>
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';

export default {
    name: 'queueComponent',
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['processOnePersone',]),
    },
}
```

Comment: There's a chance it's related to "Change Detection Caveats":
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating

Comment: Ohhh thx, I don't know about that. And how can I make it? I need a data() in App.vue? and put my reactive messages in data() ?

Comment: I believe this `state.processOnePersone[array.comp] = array.procent;` line is non-reactive. So either init `state.processOnePersone[array.comp]` with default/empty value in Vuex state() or use `Vue.set / arr.$set` in Vuex mutation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I add Vue.set in mutation. My code looks like Vue.set(state.processOnePersone, array.comp, array.procent). And now it work. Thank you men ;)

Comment: Besides, I made a quick pen not long ago: https://codepen.io/AndriusRimkus/pen/OJJPdjP
This illustrates how Vue.set got some performance implications. Since Vue.set builds a new object when the object key you assign doesn't exist, all dependent components get updated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vuex - Update entire object inside array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55287795/vuex-update-entire-object-inside-array)